# Same title for all the images

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have hundreds of images on my website and I want to keep the same title for all the images. How can I do this?

I know that I can do it one by one, but it is a tedious process and consumes a lot of time. So is there any way to change all the image titles at once?

Platform - Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can call the image something like new-photo.jpg and upload it to the media Library and on the page where the image is being shown, you can alter the dynamic code that gets the title from each image to display on the front end of the site. You can replace the dynamic code with static text. You need to find out what file is being loaded when the page/image is being displayed and they you can make some edits.

Once you find the page, I'd expect something like

```
<h2 class="title"><?php custom_code_gets_image_title();?></h2>
```

You can edit this to make it say

```
<h2 class="title">MY STATIC TEXT</h2>.
```